# ng view not working with custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have recently started learning angularJS and ran into an issue with ng-view directive. Apologies if this question is too naive.

This is my index.html file. As you can see, I am using ng-view directive to abstract out some html code from index.html file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecat">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My first app!</title>

  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"> </script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my app.js file. I am using the same partial template for all the urls.

```
angular.module('phonecat', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {templateUrl: 'partials/searchbox.html',   controller: PhoneListCtrl}).
      otherwise({templateUrl: 'partials/searchbox.html',   controller: PhoneListCtrl});
}]);
```

and this is my searchbox.html

```
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" name="s" id="s" float-up="{perspective: '100px', x: '150%'}"/>
</div>
```

and finally this is my directives.js file:

```
'use strict';

var myAppModule = angular.module('phonecat', []);

myAppModule.directive('floatUp', function() {
     return {
        // Restrict it to be an attribute in this case
          restrict: 'A',
        // responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM
          link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
             console.log("test successful");
          }
     };
 });
```

When I run this in the browser, the link function of my floatUp directive is never invoked.
When I see the rendered html of my index.html page, I get this (Note that ng-view didn't substitute the searchbox html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ng-scope" lang="en" ng-app="phonecat">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My first app!</title>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js">
<style type="text/css">
<script src="js/app.js">
<script src="js/directives.js">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-view=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Other observations:

1. When I remove the directives.js from the index.html file ng-view works perfect and searchbox shows up fine.
2. When I copy paste the searchbox.html content to the index.html file, the link function is invoked properly.

Is this a known issue? Do custom directives mess up with ng-view and make it futile. I assure you I did extensive googling before posting my question here but couldn't find any appropriate answer.

Comment: Is the filename directive.js or directives.js?    Your index.html and question description are inconsistent.

Comment: It's directives.js and what else do you find inconsistent/not clear/confusing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move this line from the directives.js

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('phonecat', []);
```

to the top of app.js

That way you're always working with the same angular module instance instead of creating new instances of it.

All your controllers, directives, and configs will then be myApModule.controller (or .config, or .directive)

Also in the app.js the references to controller in the routes should be strings `controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'` as PhoneListCtrl is not defined yet.

Your controllers.js wasn't provided but could look something like this:

```
myAppModule.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    //Controller code here
}]);
```

apps.js would now look like this:

```
myAppModule.
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {templateUrl: 'partials/searchbox.html',   controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'}).
      otherwise({templateUrl: 'partials/searchbox.html',   controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'});
}]);
```